movie where child gets heart transplant from animal
The movie is about 20-30 years old.
I don't remember many things, so please bear with me.
The story is about a child that has the heart exchanged or transplanted with the heart from a monkey or chimpanzee.
This may seem very little but I'm sure that there aren't a lot of movies with such a specific storyline, and perhaps someone remembers seeing it.
Will update the question as soon as I remember something more.

Pretty sure you could find this with a simple search for "movie monkey heart transplant". Only one comes up.

dammit. I watched the trailer and for some reason decided it wasn't the movie. checking again.

@Paulie_D - One of Slater's better movies, actually.

Untamed Heart

Caroline has not had much luck in love. Boyfriends seem to either
  leave her or cheat on her. Then she meets a shy, introverted man at
  work named Adam. When leaving work one day, two men attack her. Adam
  comes to her rescue. Unfortunately, retaliation by the attackers sends
  Adam to the hospital where he finds out he has a diseased heart. Adam
  is an orphan and was told he had a baboon's heart. He refuses a
  transplant, as he believes his love for Caroline is contained in his
  damaged heart. Before tragedy can strike, they have a passionate but
  brief romance. Adam opens up to Caroline and he, in turn, heals her
  broken heart.




http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108451/
